# ros-indigo package not found for Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ros

I have been following this tutorial for the installation of ROS on Ubuntu 14.04.1 running on VirtualBox on Windows 10.

However, I have hit a blockade where it says there is no package under the name of ros-indigo-desktop-full or ros-indigo-desktop available in the Ubuntu Package manager.

I would be grateful for any help in this regard.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to [set up the sources list and the keys](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu) necessary.

- **Set up your sources list**

  ```
  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
  ```
- **Set up your keys**

  ```
  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
  ```
- **Update the index of packages**

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- **Install ROS**

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
  ```

If you use those commands, there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: I did the exact things mentioned here, I can see the file `ros-latest.list` which has the following `deb http://packages.ros.org/ubuntu trusty main`.
However, how do I verify about the key setting up process?

Comment: What does `apt-cache search ros-indigo` return?

Comment: Thank you for the help. There was a typo in the tutorial I was following where instead of writing the repository list to /etc/apt/, I was send the command to write to /etc/opt/.. and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have enabled multiverse / universe / restricted repositories ?

Try:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-add-repository multiverse
sudo apt-add-repository restricted
sudo apt-get update
```

and the continue with the installation instructions provided by @Some progammer.

I remember facing this issue when I first installed ROS.

Comment: Yes I had enabled all the repositories. The error was a typo and the installation works now. Thank You